# Angular 2 route end on /

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would love to make url end on "/"

For example:

- localhost:8080/contacts/
- localhost:8080/feedback/

Now I use url like this:

- localhost:8080/contacts
- localhost:8080/feedback

My route config

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '',        component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'about',        component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'contacts',        component: ContactsComponent},
    {path: 'feedback',        component: FeedbackComponent},
    //{path: '**',        component: e404Component}
];
```

I use base tag in head tag

```
<base href="/"></base>
```

I try to configure my router so

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '',        component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'about/',        component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'contacts/',        component: ContactsComponent},
    {path: 'feedback/',        component: FeedbackComponent},
    //{path: '**',        component: e404Component}
];
```

but I receive an error

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'feedback'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely can have `/` in routes. Your code seems to be correct. Please check your HTML template where you have applied router-links.

You should not use:

```
[routerLink]="['feedback']" //This does not match with your path feedback/
```

Use this instead:

```
[routerLink]="['feedback/']" //This should definitely work.
```

If this does not work, please upload your template file as well to trace the error.

Comment: My template is `<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" [routerLink]="[item.link]">{{item.title}}</a>` Where "item" is the element of array. Like this `{title: 'Feedback', link: '/feedback/'}`

Comment: Router generate html `<a _ngcontent-xgi-1="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="/feedback/" ng-reflect-router-link-active-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" ng-reflect-href="/feedback" href="/feedback">Feedback</a>`

Comment: In your template's item array try without first slash. You have assigned '/feedback/' to link variable. Try 'feedback/' instead.

Comment: Router generate html `<a _ngcontent-jam-1="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="feedback/" ng-reflect-router-link-active-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" ng-reflect-href="/feedback" href="/feedback" class="active">Feedback</a>` . I set url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/feedback/` in browser and this page was redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/feedback` . Obviously it is redirected by angular because I don't use redirect. What else could it be?

Comment: Have you used <router-outlet></router-outlet>?

Comment: Yes. I'm pushed source code to the [github](https://github.com/vetalrakitin/vcard) Tag rourer-outlet can be found  [here](https://github.com/vetalrakitin/vcard/blob/master/app/components/app/template.html)